# Does the value of floatval('a.bc') exactly equals to abc/100?

Tags: php, floating-point

For example, I know 0.1 is not accurate due to floating point rounding error, however, I have another question: does

```
$num=floatval('0.1');
```

exactly equals to

```
$num=1/10
```

? Do 2 $num above rounds to the same value finally?

or in general, does

```
$num=floatval('a.bc');
```

exactly equals to

```
$num=abc/100;
```

(which abc are digits, and abc are integers)?

Comment: Im confused on what your actual question(s) is/are

Comment: One is the interpretation of a value as float, which will snap it to the nearest possible value that can be expressed. The other involves a calculation, which may exhibit different rounding properties. I would never count on accuracy either way when floats are involved. Though I can't answer the question with any amount of certainty.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, PHP does not have an official standard. [Such documentation as there is](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/) does not fully specify the semantics of [floating-point](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) operations. It does not specify which floating-point representation or format implementations must use.

That said, good practice in floating-point operations is for an operation to produce a result as if the result were first computed with infinitely precise arithmetic (exact mathematics) and then rounded according to the rounding rule in effect. (Most commonly, the rule used is to round to the nearest representable value and to round ties to the nearer value with an even low digit.)

If that rule is used, then the operation of converting the decimal numeral *a.bc* to floating-point should yield exactly the same result as  dividing the number *abc* by 100. This is because the exact mathematical result of interpreting *a.bc* as decimal equals the exact mathematical result of dividing *abc* by 100, so they both produce exactly the same result before rounding, and rounding should round them to the same representable value.

In some programming languages, such as C and C++, floating-point expressions are permitted to be evaluated with more precision than the nominal type, and floating-point expressions are permitted to be contracted, meaning that multiple operations can be combined into a single operation that would be equivalent mathematically.

An example of the former is that a programming language implementation might use `double` for doing arithmetic with values that are nominally of type `float`. If a PHP implementation did this, then *a.bc* might effectively have a different value from *abc*/100 because one is computed with `float` precision while the other is computed with `double` precision. If a particular PHP implementation is implemented using C or C++, this variation in precision could happen because the underlying C or C++ implementation does it, as permitted by the C and C++ standards.

An example of the latter is that, when computing `a*b + c`, some C or C++ implementations may choose to use an instruction that produces a result as if `a*b + c` were fully computed with exact mathematics and then rounded to the nearest representable value instead of first computing `a*b` and rounding it, then adding `c` to the rounded result and rounding a second time. I have not seen indication that PHP implementations do this. However, if they do, then it is possible that interpreting .*abc* as a decimal numeral and dividing *abc* by 100 may appear to have different results in some circumstances where extra precision is used or where they are combined with other operations.

Note that, if an implementation is using extra precision and/or contractions, the problem is not just that *a.bc* might have different value than *abc*/100. The expression *abc*/100 might appear to have different values from itself in different situations, as the implementation might use different precisions in different situations.